403 Forbidden Error when setting up Twilio Integration with ChatGPT
I am trying to create a chat app with ChatGPT. I have been trying to connect the two with python for 4 hours with now luck.
I have created a ngrok account.
when I run it, i get the forwarding url. For example: https://b877-104-61-129-181.ngrok-free.app  I add /sms to the end of it.
I then take that to twilio and insert that into "when a message comes in" URL.

I keep getting the 404 forbidden.
Le


from flask import Flask, request, abort
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
import openai
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

app = Flask(__name__)

# Set up your OpenAI API key
openai.api_key = 'secretket'  # Replace with your actual OpenAI API key

# Initialize CSRF protection
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)

@app.route("/sms", methods=['POST'])
@csrf.exempt  # Disable CSRF protection for this route
def sms_reply():
    """Respond to incoming messages using ChatGPT."""
    incoming_msg = request.form.get('Body')

    if not incoming_msg:
        abort(400)  # If no message is received, abort with a 400 Bad Request

    try:
        # Use OpenAI API to generate a response
        response = openai.Completion.create(
            engine="text-davinci-003",  # Specify the model engine
            prompt=incoming_msg,  # The SMS content is passed as the prompt
            max_tokens=150,  # Adjust this to control the length of the response
            n=1,
            stop=None,
            temperature=0.7
        )
        chatgpt_response = response.choices[0].text.strip()  # Get the response text
    except Exception as e:
        chatgpt_response = "I'm sorry, I couldn't process your request."
        # Optionally log the error for further inspection
        print(f"Error generating response: {e}")

    # Create a Twilio response
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    resp.message(chatgpt_response)  # Send the ChatGPT response as an SMS
    
    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)




Are you using a Mac?
Are you also running on port 5000?
As I ran into the same issue as documented on this stackoverflow post changing the port to something other than port 5000 worked
